# DataBinding Image.Source to a PhotoChooserTask result not working

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone

I have the following class:

```
public class Sticky : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    // ... some members

    private BitmapImage _frontPic;
    [DataMember]
    public BitmapImage FrontPic {
        get {
            return _frontPic;
        }
        set {
            _frontPic = value;
            Changed("FrontPic");
            Changed("FrontBrush");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to databind it to this XAML:

```
<Image Width="173" Height="173" Source="{Binding FrontPic}" />
```

after launching a PhotoChooserTask with this code in my PhoneApplicationPage:

```
public Sticky Sticky { get; set; }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
    Sticky = new Sticky();
    DataContext = Sticky;
}

private void ShowFrontPicPicker(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var t = new PhotoChooserTask();
    t.PixelHeight = 173;
    t.PixelWidth = 173;
    t.ShowCamera = true;

    t.Completed += (s, ev) => {
        if (ev.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK) {
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            img.SetSource(ev.ChosenPhoto);
            Sticky.FrontPic = img;
        }
    };

    t.Show();
}
```

However, my image remains blank. If I assign the Image.Source property directly to the Image without databinding, everything works. Databinding other properties works, it's just the image that seems to be the problem. How can I make the DataBinding on the image work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! The completed callback for PhotoChooserTask does not excecute in the UI thread, so a call to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` must be added:

```
t.Completed += (s, ev) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    // do stuff...
});
```